# Matching substring with regex

Tags: regex

I have lines like these ones:

```
Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1;Name=maker-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10
```

How could I match the content after `Parent=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
Parent=([^;]*)
```

It will match everything before `;` sign. I use this character because it is your separator, so it allow to match `Parent=` value even it it is not on the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that Parent is the last one, you could simply:

```
 Parent=(.+)
```